# Web API 2 Route Attribute not working?

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2, custom-routes, .net-4.5.2

OK I have spent all day looking over this code and cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

This is Web API 2 on .NET 4.5.2
Here is my Global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        new AutoFacContainer(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof (IHttpControllerSelector),
            new VersionHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiFilter.Register);
    }
}
```

- I am using AutoFac for DI, that is working.
- I have overwritten the ControllerSelector to allow for versioning via sub-folders in the Controller folder. << Yes this is actually working
- I am then calling to do the Route Registry (see below)
- Finally I am calling to add some custom filters, there are also working.

Here is my WebApi.Config

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    }
}
```

I only want to use the Route Attributes so I do not have any manual route's configured.

Finally here is my 'Default Controller'

```
[RoutePrefix("test")]
public class DefaultController : WebApiBaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult GetRoot()
    {
        return Ok("This is Version1 of GetRoot");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{test/{id:int}", Order = 1)]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult GetTest(int id)
    {
        return Ok("This is Test1 in Version1");
    }
}
```

Here is the results I get:
[image: Root Call]
[image: Test Action Call]
If I add the manual Route back in, it work but that means the Route Attribute is not working still.  So what have I missed??

Comment: Could you please change the Route to `[Route("test/{id:int}", Order = 1)]` and try?

Comment: UGH, thanks for pointing that out but it still gives me a 404

Comment: Does it work if you use the default controller selector?

Comment: I think I have too many moving parts so I am going to build a new prototype Web API and slowly take piece by piece.